# Need to stagger body parts of snake with timer

Tags: vb.net, forms, windows-forms-designer

I need to stagger each body parts release so that they dont just overlap like they do currently.

Is there a way to stagger the running of this code?

```
Public Class Form1
Public xx As New List(Of Integer)
Public yy As New List(Of Integer)
Public up As Boolean = True
Public down As Boolean = False
Public lefty As Boolean = False
Public righty As Boolean = False
Public sizey As Integer = -1
Public tik As Integer = 0
Public neww As Boolean = False
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    newpart()
    newpart()
    newpart()
End Sub

Public Sub square(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black)
    For a = 0 To sizey
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, xx(a), yy(a), 20, 20)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        righty = True
        lefty = False
        up = False
        down = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        righty = False
        lefty = True
        up = False
        down = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        righty = False
        lefty = False
        up = True
        down = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        righty = False
        lefty = False
        up = False
        down = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e _
 As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    square(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub clock_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles head.Tick
    If up = True Then
        yy(0) = yy(0) - 20
    ElseIf down = True Then
        yy(0) = yy(0) + 20
    ElseIf lefty = True Then
        xx(0) = xx(0) - 20
    ElseIf righty = True Then
        xx(0) = xx(0) + 20
    End If
    Me.Refresh()
    For b = 0 To sizey - 1
        If yy(b) - yy(b + 1) = 0 Then
            xx(b + 1) = xx(b + 1) + (xx(b) - xx(b + 1))
        ElseIf xx(b) - xx(b + 1) = 0 Then
            yy(b + 1) = yy(b + 1) + (yy(b) - yy(b + 1))

            If neww = True Then
                neww = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub newpart()
    xx.Add(100)
    yy.Add(100)
    sizey = sizey + 1
    neww = True
    Return
End Sub

End Class
```

Its mainly the bit in the clock tick as in I need it to wait another tick before running the for loop again. This edited version works but really poorly  as the third body part jumps to the first occasionally then just stays still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You over-complicated that for loop there.
Just make tail catch up before you move head. It can be done in single tick.

```
Public Class Form1
Public p As New List(Of Point)
Public direction As eDircetion = eDircetion.Up
Public Enum eDircetion
    Up
    Down
    Left
    Right
End Enum
Public sizey As Integer = -1
Public tik As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    newpart()
    newpart()
    newpart()
    head.Interval = 500
    head.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub square(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black)
    For a = 0 To sizey
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, p(a).X, p(a).Y, 20, 20)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        direction = eDircetion.Right
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        direction = eDircetion.Left
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        direction = eDircetion.Up
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        direction = eDircetion.Down
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e _
 As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    square(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub clock_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles head.Tick

    'THIS!
    For i = p.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        p(i) = p(i - 1)
    Next

    Select Case direction
        Case eDircetion.Up
            p(0) -= New Size(0, 20)
        Case eDircetion.Down
            p(0) += New Size(0, 20)
        Case eDircetion.Left
            p(0) -= New Size(20, 0)
        Case eDircetion.Right
            p(0) += New Size(20, 0)
        Case Else : Throw New Exception("Something went wrong")
    End Select

    'Me.Refresh()
    me.Invalidate() 'This is faster.
    Me.Update()

    'For b = 0 To sizey - 1
    '    If p(b).Y - p(b + 1).Y = 0 Then
    '        p(b + 1).X = p(b + 1).X + (p(b).X - p(b + 1).X)
    '    ElseIf xx(b) - xx(b + 1) = 0 Then
    '        yy(b + 1) = yy(b + 1) + (yy(b) - yy(b + 1))

    '        If neww = True Then
    '            neww = False
    '            Exit For
    '        End If
    '    End If
    'Next
End Sub

Sub newpart()
    p.Add(New Point(100, 100))
    sizey = sizey + 1
    Return
End Sub

End Class
```

I made some minor changes:

-Use enum instead of 4 booleans, makes cleaner code

-Do not use Me.Refresh, it's slow and does things you do not need here

-It's better to use not two integer lists, but one point list

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much but could you explain what your loop does in a bit more depth im a tad confused

Comment: nevermind actually i have successfully comprehended the code

Comment: The idea is simple, you start moving from the end of tail, up to head, so loop goes backwards. You just put every segment on top of next until you get to head. Next location of head you calculate in select case part.